# "This is undefined" error in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am getting a a TypeError: this is undefined, when I use this in my componentDidMount method, even though I believe I binded the method. Did I bind the method incorrectly or is there another issue? I tried to use both arrow functions and bind it in the constructor, but I am getting the same error.

````
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    // this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      email: null,
      address: null,
      address2: null,
      city: null,
      state: null,
      zip: null,
      subscribe: null,
      currentUser: null,
      displayName: null,
      uid: null,
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);


  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    firebaseRef.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

      if (user) {
        [...]
        })
        this.setState({
          uid: user.uid,
          displayName: user.displayName});

        db.collection("testCollection").doc("handleSubmitTest8").set({
          // uid:this.state.uid,
          test: "testy",

        }).then(function() {
          console.log("Document written in handleSumit in NUM");

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });

      } else {
        console.log("no user signed in");
      }

    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    [...]
  }

  handleChange(event) {
   [...]

  }
  render() {
    return (...)}}```
````

Comment: You don't need to bind lifecycle methods

Comment: Remove this line from constructor and you're good to go. 

 this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing wrong because you are using arrow function in your componentDidMount (life cycle hook method of React ). So you dont need these line of code anymore

```
 this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this); // remove this one
```

By default life cycle hook of React like componentDidMount already have this context. So you need to change your code to this.

```
componentDidMount() {

}
```

So to be clear if you are using arrow function no need to use bind(this)

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebaseRef.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        // your code
    })
}
```

if you're not familar with `this` in javascript, just use arrow function everywhere.